# Child div sticks out or relatively positioned parent div/footer problems

Tags: html, parent-child, footer

I'm having issues with my divs.  I'm trying to make a content parent dive that will stretch as posts are placed in it(wordpress theme) without the child div pertrudeing from the bottom.  I found that the key to this is to make the parent div absolute, but this creates another problem for me.  The thing is that I also want a relatively posititioned footer that moves as the content div stretches. So what I am trying to has is how can I have a "stretchy" content div and a relatively positioned footer simultaneously? Here's my css:

```
body{height: 100%; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} 
#wrapper{width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
}
#content{height: 35em;
width: 30em:
position: absolute;
padding: .62em;
margin: 5em;
}
.post{width: 12em;
height: 12em;
margin: 1em;
float: left;
}
#footer{position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

Like i said, I already tried relative positioning, but that didn't work to my liking.  I also tried the "sticky footer" method, which works fine on a large resolution screen, but displays either in front or behind the content div(depending on the z-index) on smaller res screens.  Also, if it is posible, I would prefer to not utilize JS. Any help is much appreciated!
    enter code here

Answer (score 1):

- Set overflow to auto in content,
- Change height to min-height in content,
- Have absolute elements wrapped in a relative div for happiness.

Here is a jsfiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/mAhet/

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%;">
             <div class="post">lasa sf </div>
             <div class="post"> asd asd as</div>
             <div class="post"> asd a dsadda das</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS

```
body{height: 100%; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} 
#wrapper{width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}
#content{

min-height: 35em;
width: 30em:
position: absolute;
padding: .62em;
margin: 5em;
overflow:auto;
}
.post{width: 12em;
height: 12em;
margin: 1em;
float: left;
}
#footer{position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: 1em 0 0;
}​
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mAhet/